# Do value updates automatically pass trough arguments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a Activity that contains a HashMap and a Fragment.

The Activity starts with the HashMap empty. I still pass it to the fragment as parcelable trough newInstance where I put it to the Fragment's arguments.

```
public static SelectSchoolFragment newInstance(School[] schools, HashMap<String, FavoriteInfo> favorites)
{
    SelectSchoolFragment fragment = new SelectSchoolFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelableArray(ARG_SCHOOLS, schools);

    HashMapContainer tempContainer = new HashMapContainer();
    tempContainer.data_map = favorites;
    args.putParcelable(ARG_FAVORITES,tempContainer);

    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

(The HashMapContainer is just a bare class that parcels the HashMap trough. FavoriteInfo has just two strings)

Stuff happens and my Activity gets an element to the HashMap trough onActivityResult.

I started to write code to update the fragment with the new HashMap, as the original contained in the arguments should be the same null I initialized it with, right? Yet when I rotate the screen and the fragment's OnCreate reads the values from arguments, It somehow already contains what I wrote to the Activity's copy of the HashMap.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Misc.printInfo("SelectSchoolFragment: OnCreate");
    if (getArguments() != null)
    {
        schools = (School[]) getArguments().getParcelableArray(ARG_SCHOOLS);
        mFavorites = ((HashMapContainer) getArguments().getParcelable(ARG_FAVORITES)).data_map;
    }

    adapter = new SelectSchoolRecyclerViewAdapter(schools, mFavorites,listener);
}
```

I never updated the arguments in any way, nor wrote to any bundles anywhere. And I've checked that the newInstance does not get called a second time. The Fragment does not get restarted. What I also noticed was that even when I don't rotate the screen, the new data magically appears to the fragments HashMap.

I know that java passes values the way it does, but does it really work trough Arguments AND a parcel, or is there something else going on? I find it hard to comprehend where my variable changes go when they do this.

Comment: `I know that java passes values the way it does` you mean pass by value-of-reference? There's missing bits of code I feel but from what I'm seeing here if `#getArguments` returns the same `Bundle` you made earlier, why wouldn't the map have the values you placed there?

Comment: The setArguments is called only once, with the original empty HashMap. Even if the Arguments update without calling setArguments again, the value of the HashMap that has been parceled off from the arguments shouldn't change when the original one does. That would mean the JVM is running the parceling code every time the value is changed in the Activity.